# Как поставить пароль на программу? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, пароль, password

Я создал бота на селениум. Я хочу дать его другим людям, однако не хочу, чтобы они украли мой код или распространяли программу. Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда другим давал или код или exe файл просил пароль? И как сделать так, чтобы этот пароль сбрасывался каждые например 15 дней и чтобы они были вынуждены у меня просить пароль. Или как-то ограничить доступ к программе через 15-20 дней. Работаю на winforms, но консольная версия тоже понадобится.

Answer (score 3):

я рассмотрю три возможности, которые Вам доступны.

Вы можете их сравнить, подумать, что Вам больше подходит, и выбрать.

1-й способ: пароль или ключ, "встроенный" в программу. Собственно, здесь всё понятно: Вы добавляете в программу блок кода, который проверяет наличие некоторого файла. потом этот файл как то обрабатывает, а файл содержит зашифрованную информацию о том, когда программа "купена" и до какого момента она должна работать.

Минусы очевидны: во первых, это не мешает распространить программу с ключом, и много человек одновременно будут пользоваться одной лицензией. В вторых, одна единственная проверка - не очень сложно отключается.

2-й способ: авторизация через сайт. При каждом запске программа требует логин-пароль, потом посылает эти данные на сайт, а сайт говорит, продолжать ей работать, или все, баста.

Иногда есть смысл делать такие проверки время от времени даже во время работы программы.

Способ немного лучше первого - например, он позволяет предотвратить одновременный запуск многих копий программы. Но по сути - он не очень надежный, иногда такие "защиты" взламывают, создавая "поддельный" сайт, который отвечает на запросы программы.

3-й способ: "бронебойный". Вы вообще не отдаёте прогармму кому то, а предоставлете ему сервис. Теперь Вы понимаете, почему вокруг расподилось так много сервисов?

Фактически, это означает, что некие "ключевые" действия делаются на Вашем сервере, а не в самой программе. У пользователя нет другого варианта, кроме как обратиться к серверу для какой то специальной обработки данных, потому что его программа просто не умеет этого. А при обращении к серверу всегда можно проверить лицензию.

я более-менее уверен, что Ваша программа делает какое то хитрое "сканирование сайтов". Конечно, вынести это в сервис (то есть, делать все на Вашем сервере) - затруднительно: уже после десятка активных пользователей Ваш сервер может быть заблокирован по IP по принципу "тебя слишком много, отдохни" на целевых сайтах.

Можно предложить изменение архитетуры: вы отдаёте пользователям программу, и при запуске она начинает работать как "распределенный proxy-сервер". То есть, "тупенький" бот в программе запрашивает с сайта страницу. Она целиком пересылается на Ваш сервер. Сервер знает, какие данные с этой страницы нужны, и вытаскивает их. И отправляет в ответ программе. Программа сканирует следующую страницу...

Этот способ, на мой взгляд, лучше - но требует изменения архитектуры.

Нужно взвесить, оправдывают ли усилия по защите Вашу цель. А то может получиться стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

Также, посмотрите еще [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244985/) ответ на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Если-бы можно было поставить несколько плюсиков, я бы это обязательно сделал. Отличный ответ)

Comment: @Frehzy - спасибо, доброе слово всегда приятно! На самом деле, ответ простой, он просто "приводит в порядок" уже известные факты

Comment: Спасибо. Мне подойдет простенький вариант, это не прям супер-пупер программа. Осталось понять как сделать одну из этого.